# Raspberry pi and IFTTT and Google Home

Tags: raspberry-pi, ifttt

i am trying to use my raspberry pi with google home through IFTTT but it seems that there is an error in my code.

So the situation is like this when i say "Hey google, turn on the servo", Google Mini will reply "Alright" and turn the servo.

However, i do get the reply "Alright" but my servo did not turn. Why is that so?

FYI: i am using raspberry pi 3 b+. The servo turns well without flask in the python code. Furthermore, when i access the url: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/5300, the servo did turned. What is the problem here?

This is my code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
from flask import (Flask,render_template,request, jsonify)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def index():

    p = GPIO.PWM(13,50)
    p.start(0)

    p.ChangeDutyCycle(3)
    sleep(1)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(12)
    sleep(1)

    p.stop

    return 'Hello world'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5300)
```

In my IFTTT,

For

(1) What do you want to say: Turn the $

(2) What do you want the Assistant to say in response?: Alright

(3) URL: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5300/

(4) Method: GET

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
    return 'Hello world'
```

with:

```
    print ('Request Received')
```

1. Check if 'Request Received' will appear in the console when you ask google to turn servo - means IFTTT was able to reach your raspberry pi.
2. If not, check if your port 5300 where Flask server is running is open, it might be that IFTTT can't reach RPi and you may need to forward it on the router.

Check another example on my blog [IFTTT, Python and Flask](https://maplelatte.tech/articles/software/smarter-life-with-ifttt-and-python-flask/)

Might be good to specify the HTTP method for your route decorator:

```
@app.route("/api/v1/users/", methods=['GET'])
```

Comment: When linking to external sources that you're affiliated with (like the article you linked, which you also wrote), it's important to *disclose* that affiliation. Otherwise your posts might get flagged as spam. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58884927/edit) to add that disclosure in.

Comment: To be a more specific, Stack Exchange's policy is that if you're affiliated with a link (e.g. to your own blog or something you wrote), then the post is considered spam if you don't disclose that affiliation *in your question or answer*. Please see: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [self-promotion in the help center](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035). As has been mentioned, please [edit] in disclosure.

Comment: Note that disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.